# Set User Controls Objects Properties inside a GridView ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, user-controls

I insert three template columns in my gridview. In every column I insert a user control. For example in first column there is a user control containing an image and three labels.

In my page load, I need to get list of images in a folder and create a row for each of them. Then I need to update those user controls' images in gridview columns.

Here is the sample code which gets the list of images and will be the data source of GridView:

```
        string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(Server.MapPath("~/Resources/Pictures"));
        GridView1.DataSource = filePaths;
        GridView1.DataBind();
```

In this step I can see 4 rows which have filled with RAW user controls (Empty images in image control,default text for labels etc.) Now I need to update each of them with my own properties.

Here is a picture Of my output:

[image]

As you can see in first column there are some controls (Image and Labels) which is for user control that I used them in column template of my gridview. But they are RAW and I need to update them. For example I need to update the image with the link you see in the third column.

and Here is a part of my GridView Code:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" BackColor="LightGoldenrodYellow" BorderColor="Tan" BorderWidth="1px" Caption="Image List" CellPadding="2" ForeColor="Black" GridLines="None" Height="222px" Width="409px">
    <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="PaleGoldenrod" />
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Old Picture">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <uc1:ImageColumn ID="ImageColumn1" runat="server" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="New Picture">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <uc2:ReplaceColumn ID="ReplaceColumn1" runat="server" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Allow Access">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
```

Hope it is clear enough. can any one help please?

Comment: Can you also post the markup of your GridView (part of the *.aspx)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add public properties to your user controls which you then set using "normal" data-binding expressions. E.g:

user control:

```
public class MyUserControl : UserControl
{
    public string ImageName {get; set;}
}
```

grid's template column:

```
<asp:TemplateField ...>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <uc1:MyUserControl runat="server" ImageName='<%# Eval("ImageUrl")%>' ... />
```

code-behind:

```
public class ImageVM { // view-model for data-binding
    public string ImageUrl { get; set; }
}

...

var images = LoadImages(); // returns a list of ImageVM instances
grid.DataSource = images;
grid.DataBind();
```

Comment: I did not get your codes :( I'm new in ASP, I edit my first post with some codes and a picture so I hope it is more clear now.